# Find numeric subtype (smallint, int, etc) in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I added a table in oracle in oracle with fields -

- smallint
- int
- bigint

But it internally store them as `decimal(22,0)`

Is there any way to get individual subtype (*e.g. smallint*) instead of decimal.

**My usecase:**

I am using sqoop to copy data from oracle to hive. I need to check metadata of columns of oracle table and wrote own oracle to hive data type mapping.

But I am always getting `decimal(22,0)`, so I need to map all these columns to `decimal(22,0)` in hive table even for smallint.

Comment: Trying to use `BIGINT` in a `CREATE TABLE` statement throws an exception `ORA-00902: invalid datatype`. The other two appear to just be aliases to `NUMBER(38)`.

Comment: I don't think oracle internally stores them as `decimal(22,0)`. That's the datatype you get after you map those columns outside. In fact `decimal` is internally a subtype too. `BIGINT` isn't a subtype in oracle sql. Instead of using subtypes, you might want to consider using NUMBER(x,y) with smaller values of (x, y). For inbuilt subtypes, here is the list from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm).

Comment: @MT0  my bad I am using squirrel to check data, metadata in tables.On using **create table script**, it's showing `decimal(22,0)` while on checking metadata of table `precision` is shown 38. I don't know why I am getting this discrepancy (_I am using `ojdbc6.jar` for this_)

Comment: @ruudvan check above comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data type `SMALLINT` and `INT` are just ANSI/ISO standard types which, in Oracle, [are aliases for `NUMBER(38)`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#i54335) and the `BIGINT` datatype does not exist.

If you want to store 2-byte, 4-byte and 8-byte values then you can use a combination of appropriately sized `NUMBER` columns and constraint checking to ensure the data is within the required bounds:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  small  NUMBER( 5,0) CHECK ( small  BETWEEN -POWER(2,15) AND +POWER(2,15)-1 ),
  medium NUMBER(10,0) CHECK ( medium BETWEEN -POWER(2,31) AND +POWER(2,31)-1 ),
  big    NUMBER(19,0) CHECK ( big    BETWEEN -POWER(2,63) AND +POWER(2,63)-1 )
);

INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( -POWER(2,15), -POWER(2,31), -POWER(2,63) );
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ( POWER(2,15)-1, POWER(2,31)-1, POWER(2,63)-1 );
```

Then:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

Outputs:

```
SMALL  MEDIUM      BIG
------ ----------- --------------------
-32768 -2147483648 -9223372036854775808
 32767  2147483647  9223372036854775807
```