# How to restrict oracle number(10) datatype to have max value of 2147483647

Tags: sql, oracle, sqldatatypes

I am trying to find a way in oracle to restrict number(10) data type to have max value of 2,147,483,647. According to oracle site , below are the details range given for number(10). but I can see we can add values > 2,147,483,647 until it is ten digits. Is there any way (other than adding a constraint) to restrict the value?

NUMBER(10)

Signed long integer.

Size: 4 bytes

Range: -2147483648 to +2147483647

Comment: Why do you not want to use a constraint?

Comment: Check constraints are how we enforce business rules beyond strong data-typing. So it seems a bit odd that you don't want to use one.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/37276568/1509264

Comment: You could use a check constraint (good) or you could use a trigger that throws an exception (bad)

Comment: Use a check constraint

Answer (score 14):

#### Simplest solution using a check constraint:

(Seriously, just use this solution)

```
CREATE TABLE x (i NUMBER(10) CHECK (i BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647));
```

#### Less simple (since you don't seem to want constraints):

```
CREATE TABLE x (i NUMBER(10));

CREATE TRIGGER x_int_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON x
REFERENCING NEW AS new
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :new.i NOT BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not a 32 bit integer');
  END IF;
END x_int_trg;
/
```

#### Even less simple (but cool to know):

Use a view with the `WITH CHECK OPTION` clause, and always insert/update your data through that view. Prevent direct table access by setting appropriate grants. (Of course, I'd still add the constraint nonetheless, but you don't want to).

```
CREATE TABLE x_hidden_implementation (i NUMBER(10));

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW x AS
SELECT * FROM x_hidden_implementation 
WHERE i BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

#### Go all in on `OBJECT` types:

Of course, if you really want a type, then create it!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE my_integer AS OBJECT (
  i NUMBER(10),

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION my_integer (SELF IN OUT NOCOPY my_integer, i NUMBER)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
) FINAL;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY my_integer AS
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION my_integer (SELF IN OUT NOCOPY my_integer, i NUMBER) 
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT IS
  BEGIN
    IF i NOT BETWEEN -2147483648 AND 2147483647 THEN
      raise_application_error(-20000, 'Not a 32 bit integer');
    END IF;

    SELF.i := i;
    RETURN;
  END;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE x (i my_integer);
```

Now, try inserting these. The second one will fail:

```
INSERT INTO x VALUES (my_integer(1));
INSERT INTO x VALUES (my_integer(9999999999));
```

#### Normalise it!

If you had properly normalised your schema, this wouldn't happen. Just create

```
CREATE TABLE int4 (i NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO int4
SELECT -2147483649 + level
FROM dual
CONNECT BY level <= 2 * 2147483648;
CREATE TABLE x (i NUMBER(10) REFERENCES int4);
```

Works also well for `SMALLINT` and `TINYINT`. If you buy Exadata, then you might try with `BIGINT` as well. Make sure no one modifies the table!

Credits to [Kjetil S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849967/kjetil-s) for providing this idea in the comments

#### Future Oracle

I hear standard SQL assertions are a very probably future feature in Oracle: https://community.oracle.com/ideas/13028

They're like `CHECK` constraints, but could span several tables. Of course, overengineered in your case, but at least not an actual `CHECK` constraint.

#### $$$ solution for Enterprise customers:

Oracle has you covered via the [Virtual Private Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/security/virtual-private-database/index.html) feature, if you're willing to pay and since you seem to be looking to overengineer this issue by *not* using a simple check constraint.

Just deny access to all values outside of the desired range to your database users, and you're set.

#### Hip solution using PostgreSQL

Since you didn't mention anything at all about your motivation, heck, why not use PostgreSQL as an interface for your Oracle database? You can use this implementation of an [Oracle Foreign Data Wrapper](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw) in PostgreSQL, and then declare your table something like this:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE x (
  id integer
) SERVER oracle_server OPTIONS (schema 'MY_USER', table 'X');
```

You'll get tons of other free cool features, like:

- Increased standards compliance
- Cool SQL features like the `FILTER` clause
- Actual `BOOLEAN` data types, not that `1` / `0` nonsense
- Write blog posts and put them on hackernews for tons of traffic, because PostgreSQL

Comment: Using VPD functionality to implement a simple check constraint is really enterprise-y. Pure evil genius!

Comment: @APC: Yeah, I may ask Oracle for a commission on sales due to that suggestion...

Comment: Add a `check` constaint, can't see why not. @LukasEder forgot to mention this overkill solution: create a table named I32 with just one column, fill it with all ints from -2147483648 to 2147483647 and then create a foreign key to it on the original table.

Comment: @KjetilS how do you prevent them from adding more values to I32, though

Comment: `revoke insert on i32 from humptydumty;`

Comment: I see. Well, better revoke update and delete as well, just in case.